# Axios and Node - Problems With Outputted Data on EBAY API

Tags: node.js, axios, ebay-api

I'm just trying to do a quick test using Axios to run a GET request from eBay API.

Here's my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");

var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced";
url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=XXXX";
url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
url += "&categoryId=213"; // baseball
url += "&keywords=t206"; // change value to title
url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=6";

console.log(url);

axios({
  method: "get",
  url: url
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

The URL of the string works when i input in the browser.  However when i run node, i get the following:

```
{
  findItemsAdvancedResponse: [
    {
      ack: [Array],
      version: [Array],
      timestamp: [Array],
      searchResult: [Array],
      paginationOutput: [Array],
      itemSearchURL: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to change the response console log to this

`console.log(response.data.searchResult)` and

this

```
console.log(response.data.findItemsAdvancedResponse.searchResult)
```

but i keep getting undefined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `findItemsAdvancedResponse` is an `Array`. So, do something like this

```
console.log(response.data.findItemsAdvancedResponse[0].searchResult)
```

Also beware that `searchResult` is also an array. so you have to loop over it to get all the `Results`